# c makefile rcv ranlib

Tags: c, makefile

How can I write a makefile in C?  What is advantage of using the rcv & ranlib attributes? Please explain clearly.

Sample code:

```
LIBTARGET= myfile.a 

$(LIBTARGET): $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) rcv $(LIBTARGET) $?
    ranlib $(LIBTARGET)
```

Can anybody describe why we use rcv & ranlib in this example?

Comment: The question you've asked is far too broad. You may need to do some research in order to narrow things down.

Comment: A makefile is written in its own language, not in C.  The 'rcv' options to the 'ar' command mean 'replace', 'create if necessary' and 'verbose'.  These days, 'ranlib' is usually a do-nothing program because the 'ar' program does what is needful.  Once upon a really long time ago, 'ar' did not do what 'ranlib' does, and 'ranlib' - or 'lorder' + 'tsort' - was necessary to make a usable library.

Answer (score 3):

To one of your previous attempts to ask this question I already wrote about `ar` and `ranlib`.

`ar` creates an archive (library in C is an archive), as `$(AR)` variable usually points to `ar`.

`rcv` are `ar` parameters (see `man ar` for details).

`ranlib` creates index on the archive. You cannot use unindexed archive as a library.