# makefile: how to perform “ranlib” operation correctly

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I downloaded a third party lib( [Library link](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/wordpress/software/tsnnls/)) which installs and compiles properly. It creates multiple object file (*.o), **rather than creating executable**, it's using gnu libtool to do **some scripting**. I plan to make some changes in some function; however, given I am new to linux, I thought to avoid libtool and just create executable.

**I wrote a small makefile to link multiple object files and libraries and create an executable**. All object files already exists. One library is as archive file (**libtaucs.a**). Based on online resouce, I came to know that I have to perform "ranlib" utlity as suggested here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286441/c-makefile-rcv-ranlib). However, I get the following error:

```
 $ make
make: *** No rule to make target `ranlib', needed by `test_me_DKU'.  Stop.
```

Here is my makefile which I am using to link already existing object file (disclaimer: I barely understand makefile;so, you may find lots of error)

```
# Here is a simple Make Macro.
LINK_TARGET = test_me_DKU

# Here is a Make Macro that uses the backslash to extend to multiple lines.
##OBJS =  tsnnls_test.o

OBJS =  libtsnnls_la-taucs_malloc.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_ops.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_vec_base.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_complex.o libtsnnls_la-colamd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdbar.o libtsnnls_la-amdexa.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdtru.o libtsnnls_la-genmmd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_timer.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_sn_llt.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_base.o libtsnnls_la-tlsqr.o \
    libtsnnls_la-tsnnls.o libtsnnls_la-lsqr.o   \
    tsnnls_test.o


# Here is a Make Macro defined by two Macro Expansions.
# A Macro Expansion may be treated as a textual replacement of the Make Macro.
# Macro Expansions are introduced with $ and enclosed in (parentheses).
REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)


clean : 
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)   
    echo Clean done


all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All done


RANLIB = ranlib
LIBTARGET= /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a 

tsnnls_test_LDADD = $(LDADD)
LIBS = -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath $? $(RANLIB) $(LIBTARGET) -lm 


# Here is a Rule that uses some built-in Make Macros in its command:
# $@ expands to the rule's target, in this case "test_me.exe".
# $^ expands to the rule's dependencies, in this case the multiple files
# defined in OBJS (*.o)
$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)   $(tsnnls_test_LDADD) $(LIBS)  
    g++ -g -o $@ $^
```

Also, can someone please also explain this command ?

```
g++ -g -o $@ $^
```

Comment: The last line runs `g++` with the `-g` (debuggable output) and `-o` (output file name; that's the `$@`, which maps to `$(LINK_TARGET)`, which is `test_me_DKU`) options, plus all the object files and libraries it depends on (`$^` — a GNU `make` extension).

Comment: I think the problem arises from the line `LIBS = -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath $? $(RANLIB) $(LIBTARGET) -lm`, where the `$?` and `$(RANLIB)` are almost certainly interlopers, and I'm suspicious that the `$(LIBTARGET)` doesn't belong.  A command somewhere containing `$(RANLIB) $(LIBTARGET)` would make some sense.  But adding `$(RANLIB)` to the libraries linked is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you put `$(tsnnls_test_LDADD)` and `$(LIBS)` in the prerequisites line. That isn't correct. You want those on the linking line. They are flags to the linker.

You also don't want `ranlib` in `LIBS` because it is a command that needs to be run and not a flag to the linker.

That all being said you don't appear to be creating a static library (`.a` file) so you shouldn't need `ranlib` at all. Alternatively, since you probably **do** want to be making a library and **not** an executable (binary). You need to run `ranlib` on the `.a` file as indicated in the question/answer you linked.

Comment: The static file "libtaucs.a" is part of "TAUCS" library and I need to link that. Also, I am very new to linux and makefile stuffs; so, would you please also let me know what do you mean by linking line? Do you mean doing something like this: $(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)   $(tsnnls_test_LDADD) $(LIBS)  $(RANLIB) $(LIBTARGET)
 g++ -g -o $@ $^

Comment: You don't need `ranlib` to *use* a static library. Just to create one. And the "linking line" is the command line that links your object/executable. In your makefile that is `g++ -g -o $@ $^` which also, as indicated in my answer, needs `$(tsnnls_test_LIBADD) $(LIBS)` added to it since those contain arguments to the linker. But you don't need to link to the individual object files **and** the static library, just one or the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. It compiles properly.